# eliminar valores repetidos de un grupo con SQL SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero eliminar valores duplicados de una tabla sql pero no he podido eliminar solo tengo esta query que cuenta los valores repetidos de cada grupo, como puedo agregarle un delete a esta query?, Esta query ya esta filtrada solo no se como colocarle el DELETE

```html
select TRANSIT_F, count(*)
from TBL  where ID_CARGA in (3940630,
3940631,
3940632,
3940633,
3940634,
3940635,
3940636,
3940637,
3940638,
3940639,
3940640,
3940641,
3940642)
group by TRANSIT_F
having count(TRANSIT_F) > 1
```

Lo que quiero eliminar son los repetidos de cada registro, en una columna tengo el valor unico y en la otra el numero de veces que se encuentra repetido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de cada grupo me interesa solo las que estan marcadas, ya que las otras filas del mismo grupo son identicas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cada fila se repite de manera idéntica? ¿Podrías agregar una muestra con los datos completos de  un caso con las 3 filas repetidas? esto puede determinar el tipo de solución que podamos darte, una cosa es si las filas son idénticas o bien solo necesitas quedarte con la última fila de cada grupo.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ya he agregado una imagen con la muestra de como están mis registros, de cada grupo hay un registro diferente y ese es el que me interesa, los que se repiten los quiero eliminar

Comment: ¿Los que has pintado de amarillo son los que quieres conservar? o ¿De las tres filas que parecen duplicadas solo quieres dejar una? Sería bueno que agregues los nombres de cada columna, en la imagen justo están cortados estos datos.

Comment: las que pinte de amarillo son las filas que quiero conservar, las filas que aparecen triplicadas las quiero eliminar

Comment: Las que NO están en amarillo son idénticas entre si pero no son idénticas con las que si están en amarillo. De todas formas si quieres eliminar las tres filas de cada caso, es bastante simple `delete TBL where TRANSIT_F IN (<tu consulta solo TRANSIT_F a borrar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asi elimine los registros repetidos

```html
DELETE FROM TBL WHERE TRANSIT_F IN (select TRANSIT_F
FROM TBL WHERE ID_CARGA IN (3940632,
3940633,
3940634,
3940635,
3940636,
3940637,
3940638,
3940639) 
GROUP BY TRANSIT_F
HAVING COUNT(TRANSIT_F) > 1) AND ID_CARGA IN (3940632,
3940633,
3940634,
3940635,
3940636,
3940637,
3940638,
3940639)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar row_number para disponer de todos los registros repetidos, y eliminarlos quedando solo uno de esos valores. 
Pero en la imagen que muestras como discernir entre los que se tienen que quedar o ir si tienen valores diferentes en alguna columna
Si la columna que pone 000046251 se puede utilizar para esto.

```
;with cte as (
select TRANSIT_F,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRANSIT_F ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROW

from TBL  
where ID_CARGA in (3940630,
                    3940631,
                    3940632,
                    3940633,
                    3940634,
                    3940635,
                    3940636,
                    3940637,
                    3940638,
                    3940639,
                    3940640,
                    3940641,
                    3940642)
)
SELECT * FROM 
cte WHERE ROW > 1
```

Cuando tengas confirmado, que son los registros que quieres eliminar, solo tienes que cambiar el select * from por un delete from cte where row > 1

Existen más posibilidades, pero deberías postear como es tú tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

1) Crea una vista con tu consulta en la que extraes los duplicados:

```
create view vduplicados(TRANSIT_F, cantidad) as
select TRANSIT_F, count(*)
from TBL  where ID_CARGA in (3940630,
3940631,
3940632,
3940633,
3940634,
3940635,
3940636,
3940637,
3940638,
3940639,
3940640,
3940641,
3940642)
group by TRANSIT_F
having count(TRANSIT_F) > 1;
```

2) Ahora elimina de tu tabla los ids que aparezcan en la vista vduplicados:

```
delete from TBL where TRANSIT_F in (select TRANSIT_F from vduplicados);
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Esto elimina todos los registros duplicados, el OP quiere eliminar "los repetidos de cada registro". Si el '3940641' está triplicado, quiere eliminar 2 de ellos.